# In R/dplyr, when using 'pivot_wide' to reshape the dataframe, how to sum the numeric with the reshape process

Tags: r, dplyr

When using pivot_wide to reshape the dataframe, how to sum the numeric with the reshape process?

As below, when i use `test_data %>% pivot_wider(names_from ='category',values_from ='amount' )`,
the result variables 'A'/'B'  are stored as 'list' (i want the sum the figures in the list).

I use  `test_data %>% spread(key='category',value='amount')`, the error show '`Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys`'

```
library(tidyverse)
test_data <- data.frame(
      category=c('A','A','A','B','B','B'),
      sub_category=c('a','b','b','a','b','b'),
      amount=1:6
    )
    
    test_data %>% pivot_wider(names_from ='category',values_from ='amount' ) # method 1,the reuslt stored as 'list'
    
    test_data %>% spread(key='category',value='amount') # methon 2,failed
```

[image]

Comment: Use the `values_fn` argument (see `?pivot_wider`)

Comment: test_data %>% pivot_wider(names_from ='category',values_from ='amount',values_fn=sum)   , add 'values_fn=sum' to the code can solve it.  Thanks!